# Escaped html quotes not being recognised

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table as follows:

```
<p>
        <table id="modTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                    <th>Deaths</th>
                    <th>Attended?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>user1</td>
                    <td><select name="eventRole">
                    <option value="referee" selected="selected">Referee</option>
                    <option value="assRef">Ass Ref</option>
                    <option value="player">Player</option>
                    <option value="monster">Monster</option></select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="eventPoints" maxlength="2" size="2" value="36"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="attended" checked></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>user2</td>
                    <td><select name="eventRole">
                    <option value="referee">Referee</option>
                    <option value="assRef">Ass Ref</option>
                    <option value="player" selected="selected">Player</option>
                    <option value="monster">Monster</option></select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="eventPoints" maxlength="2" size="2" value="36"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="eventDeaths" maxlength="1" size="1" value="0"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="attended" checked></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</p></form><div id="addrows">ADD NEW</div>
```

And a piece of JQuery which adds a new row to the table as follows:

```
$(function() {$("#addrows").click(function(){  
    $("#modTable").append("<tr> <td><select name=&quot;username&quot;><option value=&quot;112&quot;>3rd spearman</option><option value=&quot;40&quot;>Alex</option><option value=&quot;157&quot;>alex.kynoch</option><option value=&quot;23&quot;>AndyK</option><option value=&quot;181&quot;>AndyL</option><option value=&quot;27&quot;>AndyMc</option></select></td><td><select name=&quot;eventRole&quot;><option value=&quot;referee&quot;>Referee</option><option value=&quot;assRef&quot;>Ass Ref</option><option value=&quot;player&quot;>Player</option><option value=&quot;monster&quot;>Monster</option></select></td><td><input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;eventPoints&quot; maxlength=&quot;2&quot;></td><td><input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;eventDeaths&quot; maxlength=&quot;1&quot;></td><td><input type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;attended&quot; checked></td> </tr>") 
});
             });
```

It's all working fine, when you click "add New" a new row appears, HOWEVER, the new form fields aren't formatted properly - The checkbox isn't a checkbox, and I can't seem to format any of the fields using their attributes (e.g. size="2")

I'm guessing that this is because of the HTML entities I've used in the JQuery to escape the double quotes, but if I use ACTUAL double quotes then it stop the JQuery from running... Can anybody suggest how I can make this work because I'm at a dead end!

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtrcjrqf/

Comment: But even when I escape the quotes (I'd tried that before using html entities) It doesn't work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/vtrcjrqf/2/

Comment: That works just fine. You've just left off the `size` attribute on the text inputs.

Comment: Oops... Yeah, you're right... My fault! Fixed... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you typed this into your HTML directly:

```
<input type=&quot;checkbox&quot; name=&quot;attended&quot; checked>
```

...would you expect the browser to parse it correctly? You don't use entities for the quotes around attribute values. And you don't with the HTML you pass jQuery, either.

If you want to have a double quote within a double-quoted JavaScript string, use a backslash:

```
var foo = "I'm in a double-quoted string, \"and this part is in double quotes\"";
```

Or, of course, use a single-quoted string and escape single quotes instead:

```
var foo = 'I\'m in a single-quoted string, "and this part is in double quotes"';
```

---

Side note: If you find you have a lot of HTML in strings in your JavaScript code, consider using a templating engine or the new `template` element instead, so you can author markup in your markup editor/designer rather than your JavaScript code editor. And **particularly** if you have *duplicated* HTML (once in your HTML, then again in your JavaScript), you really don't want to put the HTML in the code, because they'll get out of sync. For instance, in a comment on the question, you said you "still" didn't get what you expected when escaping the quotes with a backslash in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtrcjrqf/2/). The main problem with that fiddle is that the HTML in the code *isn't the same* as the HTML in the HTML; you've left the `size` attribute off the text inputs (at least). Of course, the HTML in your code isn't *exactly* the same (you have a select rather than straight text), but differences like that can readily be handled.

---

Side note 2: Another problem is that you're appending rows to your `table` element, when you should be appending to the `tbody` element within it.

---

Side note 3: It's invalid to have a `table` element inside a `p` element; `p` elements [can contain *phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), but `table` elements [are *flow content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

---

Here's an example of not repeating the HTML; the `current` array could be output by server-side dynamic script rendering, or retrieved via ajax:

```js
$(function() {
  // Current data
  var current = [
    {
      name: "user1",
      role: "referee",
      points: 36,
      deaths: null,
      attended: true
    },
    {
      name: "user2",
      role: "player",
      points: 36,
      deaths: 0,
      attended: true
    }
  ];

  // Get the table body
  var tbody = $("#modTable tbody");

  // Get our row model and remove it
  var rowModel = tbody.find("tr").remove();

  // Show the current entries
  current.forEach(function(entry) {
    addRow(entry);
  });

  // Let the user add more
  $("#addrows").click(function() {
    addRow();
  });

  function addRow(entry) {
    // Clone our model
    var row = rowModel.clone();

    // If we have an entry, fill it in
    if (entry) {
      // Replace the select with the name
      row.find("select[name=username]").closest("td").text(entry.name);

      // Fill in fields
      row.find("select[name=eventRole]").val(entry.role);
      if (entry.points === null) {
        row.find("input[name=eventPoints]").remove();
      } else {
        row.find("input[name=eventPoints]").val(entry.points);
      }
      if (entry.deaths === null) {
        row.find("input[name=eventDeaths]").remove();
      } else {
        row.find("input[name=eventDeaths]").val(entry.deaths);
      }
      row.find("input[name=attended]").prop(entry.attended);
    }

    // Add it
    tbody.append(row);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<table id="modTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Deaths</th>
      <th>Attended?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="username">
          <option value="112">3rd spearman</option>
          <option value="40">Alex</option>
          <option value="157">alex.kynoch</option>
          <option value="23">AndyK</option>
          <option value="181">AndyL</option>
          <option value="27">AndyMc</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="eventRole">
          <option value="referee">Referee</option>
          <option value="assRef">Ass Ref</option>
          <option value="player">Player</option>
          <option value="monster">Monster</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventPoints" maxlength="2" size="2" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="eventDeaths" maxlength="1" size="1" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="attended">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</p>
<div id="addrows">ADD NEW</div>
```

Comment: Besides, in the given case (and many others), the quotes could simply be omitted, e.g. `name=username`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Quite true. Author would need to be clear on the rules, but for things like `type` and `selected`, absolutely.